# Laravel inner join of inner join

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

I have the following query in my controller, with all column names verified:

```
$types = DB::table('cemetery_charge_types')
            ->join('payment_details', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payment_details.payable_id')
            ->join('invoices', 'cemetery_charge_types.id', '=', 'invoices.charge_type_id')
            ->select('cemetery_charge_types.*', DB::raw('SUM(payment_details.amount) as amount'),'invoices.*')
            ->whereIn('payment_details.payment_id', $payments->pluck('id'))
            ->get();
```

I have made sure all of the column names are correct, along with their tables, but I get the following error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'invoices.id' in 'on clause'....`

I have a table with charge types, which can have multiple invoices, who in turn can have multiple payment_details.

Comment: How cheery :-(. Anyway, just out of curiosity, what happens when you swap the joins around

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of your joins like this:

```php
$types = DB::table('cemetery_charge_types')
    ->join('invoices', 'cemetery_charge_types.id', '=', 'invoices.charge_type_id')
    ->join('payment_details', 'invoices.id', '=', 'payment_details.payable_id')
    ->select('cemetery_charge_types.*', DB::raw('SUM(payment_details.amount) as amount'),'invoices.*')
    ->whereIn('payment_details.payment_id', $payments->pluck('id'))
    ->get();
```